Installing Pyspark locally
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType 
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


spark = ( 
 SparkSession
 .builder
 .master("local[*]")
 .appName('test')
 .getOrCreate()
)

data = [ 
 ("James","","Smith","36636","M",3000),
 ("Michael","Rose","","40288","M",4000),
 ("Robert","","Williams","42114","M",4000),
 ("Maria","Anne","Jones","39192","F",4000),
 ("Jen","Mary","Brown","","F",-1) 
]

schema = (
 StructType([
  StructField("firstname",StringType(),True),
  StructField("middlename",StringType(),True), 
  StructField("lastname",StringType(),True),
  StructField("id", StringType(), True),
  StructField("gender", StringType(), True),
  StructField("salary", IntegerType(), True)
   ])
)

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=schema)

df.printSchema()

df.show()

I installed the most current version of Python, Spark and Haddop
I installed Java 8 jdk and jre
In these folders
C:/spark
C:/hadoop
I created environment and path variables
HADOOP_HOME
C:\Spark\
SPARK_HOME
C:\Spark\
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON
jupyter
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS
notebook
PYSPARK_PYTHON
python
I managed to run the installation but I can't show the tables with the df.show() command
The other command df.printSchema(), as you can see, works normally.
Below is the error return:
Jeff@DESKTOP-SJGBAM2 MINGW64 /d/scripts_spark
$ C:/Users/Jeff/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe d:/scripts_spark/main.py
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
24/05/05 22:48:01 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
root
 |-- firstname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- middlename: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lastname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- gender: string (nullable = true)
 |-- salary: integer (nullable = true)

24/05/05 22:48:06 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)/ 1]
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:612)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:594)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:789)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:766)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:525)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory$WholeStageCodegenPartitionEvaluator$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory.scala:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:388)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:893)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:893)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:774)
        ... 26 more
24/05/05 22:48:06 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (DESKTOP-SJGBAM2 executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:612)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:594)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:789)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:766)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:525)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory$WholeStageCodegenPartitionEvaluator$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory.scala:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:388)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:893)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:893)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:774)
        ... 26 more

24/05/05 22:48:06 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):                                  (0 + 0) / 1]
  File "d:\scripts_spark\main.py", line 36, in <module>
    df.show()
  File "C:\Users\Jeff\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py", line 945, in show
    print(self._show_string(n, truncate, vertical))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Jeff\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py", line 963, in _show_string
    return self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Jeff\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Jeff\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py", line 179, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Jeff\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o39.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (DESKTOP-SJGBAM2 executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:612)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:594)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:789)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:766)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:525)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory$WholeStageCodegenPartitionEvaluator$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory.scala:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:388)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:893)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:893)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:774)
        ... 26 more

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2856)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2792)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1247)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1247)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1247)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3060)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2994)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2983)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:989)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2398)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2419)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2438)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:530)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:483)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:4332)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$head$1(Dataset.scala:3314)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$2(Dataset.scala:4322)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.withInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:546)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:4320)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:201)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:900)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:4320)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:3314)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:3537)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:280)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:315)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:612)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:594)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:789)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:766)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:525)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory$WholeStageCodegenPartitionEvaluator$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory.scala:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:388)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:893)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:893)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:774)
        ... 26 more

ÊXITO: o processo com PID 7116 (processo filho de PID 3764) foi finalizado.
ÊXITO: o processo com PID 3764 (processo filho de PID 3684) foi finalizado.
ÊXITO: o processo com PID 3684 (processo filho de PID 1744) foi finalizado.

redid the environment variables
I reinstalled spark

Downgrade python to python==3.11.8 and it should work.

thanks! It worked out
I was also thinking it would be a problem with Java and updated to the latest version.
But I think the issue was really the Python version
Thank you very much!!!

Happy to help! I would really appreciate if you could upvote my comment, it will encourage me to contribute more to our community.
